# how to write a mathematical formula in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a formula  that does the following :
-takes the LOS_Day (calculated datediff with two fields AdmitDate and DischargeDate)and multiplies it by 100 then divides it is by NumberofBeds (was calculated using the Count Function from V_Bed table)and multiplies it by input date range (number of days) from the user@fromdate @todate

[image]

find below the query used

```
       SELECT pt.regcode, 
       pt.admissionnumber, 
       pt.admissionid, 
       pt.admitdate, 
       pt.dischargedate, 
       wardbed.bedid, 
       bed.bedname, 
       wardbed.ward, 
       Datediff(hour, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate) AS LOS_Hour, 
       Datediff(day, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate)  AS LOS_day, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   v_beds)                                AS NumberofBeds 
FROM   v_bedallocations bed, 
       v_dbpatientadmissions pt, 
       v_beds wardbed 
WHERE  pt.admissionnumber = bed.admissionnumber 
       AND pt.admissionid = wardbed.admissionid 
       AND bed.bedname = wardbed.bedname 
GROUP  BY bed.bedname, 
          pt.regcode, 
          pt.admissionnumber, 
          pt.admissionid, 
          pt.admitdate, 
          pt.dischargedate, 
          wardbed.bedid, 
          bed.bedname, 
          wardbed.ward
```

find below the Output 
[image]

Comment: Use isnull() function like `isnull(pt.DischargeDate,getdate())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the null value to `GetDate()` in your select statement before using it, for this you can use `ISNULL(pt.dischargedate,GETDATE())` in your select statement itself.

Following is the updated query with `ISNULL` on `dischargedate`

```
      SELECT pt.regcode, 
       pt.admissionnumber, 
       pt.admissionid, 
       pt.admitdate, 
       pt.dischargedate, 
       wardbed.bedid, 
       bed.bedname, 
       wardbed.ward, 
       Datediff(hour, pt.admitdate, ISNULL(pt.dischargedate, GETDATE())) AS LOS_Hour, 
       Datediff(day, pt.admitdate, ISNULL(pt.dischargedate,GETDATE()))  AS LOS_day, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   v_beds)                                AS NumberofBeds 
FROM   v_bedallocations bed, 
       v_dbpatientadmissions pt, 
       v_beds wardbed 
WHERE  pt.admissionnumber = bed.admissionnumber 
       AND pt.admissionid = wardbed.admissionid 
       AND bed.bedname = wardbed.bedname 
GROUP  BY bed.bedname, 
          pt.regcode, 
          pt.admissionnumber, 
          pt.admissionid, 
          pt.admitdate, 
          pt.dischargedate, 
          wardbed.bedid, 
          bed.bedname, 
          wardbed.ward
```